# RxJava: how do you flush a timed buffer?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm creating this PublishProcessor that save to the database its element every 10 seconds:

```
    val publishProcessor = PublishProcessor.create<Entity>()

    publishProcessor
        .buffer(10, SECONDS)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            { saveToDatabase(it) },
            { Log.e("TAG", "Error: $it") })
        .addTo(compositeDisposable)
```

When my activity finish, I want to flush everything that is in the current buffer, and not wait 10 seconds. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Have another subject as the buffer boundary that is merged with an interval:

```java
PublishSubject<Entity> publishProcessor = PublishSubject.create();

Subject<Long> flush = PublishSubject.<Long>create().toSerialized();

publishProcessor
    .buffer(flush.mergeWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(...)

flush.onNext(1L);
```

If you want to also reset the timer upon a manual flush

```java
publishProcessor
    .buffer(
        flush.mergeWith(Observable.timer(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        .take(1)
        .repeat()
    )
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thanks David! I created a gist with an example and test [here](https://gist.github.com/skykelsey/6035180c093a9b8bb1e0b07223b53d63) if anyone is interested.

Comment: Also, Are you able to explain what exactly `repeat()` is doing here? I would naively expect `repeat()` to just return a `Unit`, but it looks like it's returning the result of `merge()` instead, which allows the interval to be reset?

Comment: Timer is 1 shot and take(1) will only accept one signal. The repeat is there to ensure a fresh timer and a fresh connection to the flush is established over and over.