# RxJava: how to flush a fixed-size buffer

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java

I'm using `PublishProcessor<Log> logStream` to implement the logging logic in the Rx manner.

Produce:

```java
logStream.onNext(Log)
```

Consume:

```java
logStream
    .subscribeOn(Subscribers.io())
    .buffer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 300)
    .subscribe(dumpLogs, errorHandler)
```

The log messages will be cached in the RxJava buffer with the fixed duration (1s) and maximum size (300) specified.

Now I'd like to add a new logic: dump the logs immediately when needed. I've searched it with Google and StackOverflow for a while, but still don't know how to implement it.

Currently the best way I know is to merge a `subject` with the interval (refer to [RxJava: how do you flush a timed buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870523/rxjava-how-do-you-flush-a-timed-buffer)), and then flush the buffer by `subject.onNext()`.

However, this approach does not support size limit on the buffer. Is there any better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could modify the code in the other answer you linked as follows, introducing a second subscription to the `PublishSubject` that increments and `AtomicInteger` after each value:

```
    PublishSubject<String> publishProcessor = PublishSubject.create();
    Subject<Long> flush = PublishSubject.<Long>create().toSerialized();
    AtomicInteger bufferSize = new AtomicInteger();
    int maxBufferSize = 100;
    
    publishProcessor
        .buffer( flush.mergeWith( Observable.timer( 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ))
            .take( 1 )
            .repeat() )
        .observeOn( Schedulers.io() )
        .doOnNext( buffer -> bufferSize.set( 0 ))
        .subscribe( /*...*/ );

    publishProcessor.map( val -> bufferSize.incrementAndGet() )
        .filter( size -> size == maxBufferSize )
        .subscribe( size -> flush.onNext( 1L ));
    
    // manual flush
    flush.onNext( 1L );
```

Comment: Thanks. Overall it works well. But since now we have two subscribers for the `publishProcessor`, the order in which they receive events is not guaranteed, which means, when a new log comes in and makes `bufferSize` equal to `maxBufferSize`, it might have not been stored in the buffer yet. So the amount of logs being flushed sometimes is not exactly the same as `maxBufferSize`. But it should suffice for our use case.